# Improve and simplify a JS reduce method using lodash or some modern method to have better readability of the code

Tags: javascript

I built the following method using reduce to reduce data from DB to a better shape for my needs and would like to know how to simplify it and make it better

```js
const dbData = [{
    studyId: "X",
    siteId: "A",
    day: "2000-01-01",
    status: "PENDING_CALLCENTER",
    current: 5,
    total: 17
  },
  {
    studyId: "X",
    siteId: "A",
    day: "2000-01-01",
    status: "PENDING_SITE",
    current: 3,
    total: 9
  },
  {
    studyId: "Y",
    siteId: "B",
    day: "2000-01-01",
    status: "PENDING_SITE",
    current: 3,
    total: 9
  },
  {
    studyId: "Y",
    siteId: "B",
    day: "2000-01-01",
    status: "PENDING_CALLCENTER",
    current: 3,
    total: 9
  }
];

const reduced = dbData.reduce((acc, row) => {
  const {
    studyId,
    siteId,
    status,
    current,
    total
  } = row;
  const idx = acc.findIndex(
    (x) => studyId === x.studyId && siteId === x.siteId
  );
  const item =
    idx === -1 ?
    {
      studyId,
      siteId,
      currents: {},
      totals: {}
    } :
    { ...acc[idx]
    };
  item.currents[status] = item.currents[status] ?
    item.currents[status] + current :
    current;
  item.totals[status] = item.totals[status] ?
    item.totals[status] + total :
    total;
  if (idx === -1) {
    acc.push(item);
  } else {
    acc[idx] = item;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(reduced);
```

The method gets data like from the example an array of objects where we have as a duplicate the same `studyId` and `siteId` and that data contains always a different `status`.

The method needs to aggregate this data in one object per the same `studyId` and `siteId` like the result of the snippet including all the statuses divided by `currents` and `totals.`

As a simple example, we will never have the same data for status for that study and site plus the current and total are related to that status only

```
{
studyId: A
siteId: 1
status: PENDING_CALLCENTER
current: 1
total: 1
}
{
studyId: A
siteId: 1
status: PENDING_SITE
current: 3
total: 5
}
{
studyId: A
siteId: 1
status: ANOTHER_STATUS
current: 34
total: 50
}
```

The above will be resulting as follow

```
{
studyId: A
siteId: 1
currents: [{
   PENDING_CALLCENTER: 1
   PENDING_SITE: 3
   ANOTHER_STATUS: 34  
}]
totals: [{
   PENDING_CALLCENTER: 1
   PENDING_SITE: 5
   ANOTHER_STATUS: 50  
}]
}
```

In this way, that data is altogether making it easier to use in further steps.

What I need to understand is how can I make this better as I do not really like the way I found it with reduce, for example, that reduce can be improved or can be used lodash to get same result or another method approach.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `findIndex` with the accumulator being an array, you can have an object instead, indexed by a unique key for a given combination of a studyId and siteId.

Instead of the conditional operator to check if the nested value exists when trying to add, you can alternate the existing value `?? 0` so that it defaults to 0 if the value isn't found, which makes the syntax a bit easier.

```js
const dbData=[{studyId:"X",siteId:"A",day:"2000-01-01",status:"PENDING_CALLCENTER",current:5,total:17},{studyId:"X",siteId:"A",day:"2000-01-01",status:"PENDING_SITE",current:3,total:9},{studyId:"Y",siteId:"B",day:"2000-01-01",status:"PENDING_SITE",current:3,total:9},{studyId:"Y",siteId:"B",day:"2000-01-01",status:"PENDING_CALLCENTER",current:3,total:9}];

const dataByKey = {};
for (const { studyId, siteId, status, current, total } of dbData) {
  const key = `${studyId}_${siteId}`;
  const thisData = dataByKey[key] ??= {
    studyId,
    siteId,
    currents: {},
    totals: {}
  };
  thisData.currents[status] = (thisData.currents[status] ?? 0) + current;
  thisData.totals[status] = (thisData.totals[status] ?? 0) + total;
}

console.log(Object.values(dataByKey));
```

A semi-common pattern I see some people use, that I think is a slight mistake, is to use `.reduce` when transforming an array into an object (or into an array that isn't one-to-one or a filter of the original array). IMO, using a plain loop is both easier to read and easier to write in most circumstances. See: [Is reduce bad?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

Comment: what do you think of reduce in grouping problems. this kind of looks like one. ive seen it on top answers for grouping problems as well

Comment: When it comes to reducing into a non-primitive, I usually don't like it, because often in such a situation the non-primitive could be declared outside and the code would be easier to understand. Just because reduce *can* be used to turn an array into an object doesn't mean it *should* be used for all such situations. (Like a `for (let i...` loop, it's very flexible - often at the slight expense of readability)

Comment: This is a nice answer and very useful but unfortunately in the project, I'm applying this I have a strict rule to not use for loops so I cannot use it even though is very nice

Comment: @Jakub I guess you could use `forEach` instead, if that's allowed, the effect is no different from `for..of`... but if that's permitted then the rule seems pretty dumb

Comment: I tried this https://pastebin.com/XtJb9pN2 but what is the way to make this return as [{},{}, ...] right now is returning an OBJ only

Comment: @Jakub Like in the answer, take the values from the object - `Object.values`

Comment: Yes I did as forgot initially and the last question I can use forEach how to avoid on dataKey[key] is the error Unexpected chained assignment in this situation. I cannot change the rule so how can I have this differently written

Comment: @Jakub `const thisData = dataByKey[key] ??= {` makes things nice and concise, but if you're not allowed to do that you can do `dataByKey[key] ??= { ... }; const thisData = dataByKey[key];`

Comment: Regarding the key is possible to not print out the `${studyId}_${siteId}` as I just realized this is printed in front of the obj an I should not have anything

Comment: @Jakub Use not the object (which has those keys), but only the object's values - `Object.values(dataByKey)` as in the answer